# Add webpage to Yii project

Tags: php, yii

I've a website, which was build by someone else in Yii framework, which at the top has a NavBar containing links to web-pages in the project. Now I want to add a webpage to the project and its link to the NavBar. I'm quite unfamiliar with Yii but I know a little bit of PHP. Would you please guide me to this?

Many thanks.

Comment: probably somewhere in views/layouts folder (maybe main.php file) you will find your navbar

Comment: @Code717 yeah it does have the data for the navbar, Thanks a lot. Now as that I have added my new webpage link into the navbar, it I need to modify my webpage to fit the Yii MVC.

Comment: how does data for navbar look? Does it have same items as menu in your website?

Comment: @Code717, yeah it does. I've been able to add my new webpage link into the navbar. Now I need to convert my .php file (the new webpage) into the MVC layout

Comment: add your new action to controller and render your new created view file (your .php file). Can you show for example any link from your navbar?

Comment: @Code717 The navbar is like this: 'array('label'==>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/home')), .....'

Comment: @Code717 can you please show me an example of "how to add your new action to controller and render new created view file" ?

Comment: So you probably have SiteController in "controllers" folder with action actionHome(). So same way you can add your new page lets say 'mypage' so link would be  `'url'=>array('/site/mypage'))` and then in controller add `function actionMypage()` and your view file 'mypage.php' in views/site folder.

Comment: @Code717 yeah that is there, I've added that and now it says "Error 500 Undefined Variable form"
Actually I've defined a <form> tag in my new webpage and this is giving error because of that??

Comment: can you show your controller action you've added and view file you've created?

Comment: @code717 controller action has actually nothing except rendering the view, as I've mentioned earlier, the view file is actually the whole webpage that I've created earlier, I shouldn't add or edit that file before adding it to view??

Comment: it is hard to say something without seeing the actual code